# How to force load a page in Twebbrowser control when this is not visible

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

i need to execute some javascript functions from delphi code, but this functions fails if the page is not loaded in the Twebbrowser  control. so  the problem is if  page is located in a tabshet wich is not active the page is not loaded until the tabsheet is become active.

the question is  How to force load a page in  a `Twebbrowser` control when this is not visible.

to test this behaviour just put a pagecontrol, with 2 tabsheets , and a twebbrowser in the second tabsheet, now in the oncreate event of the form put this code

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

now when you run the app the page only loads when you makes the second tabsheet visible.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070084/delphi-missing-ui-control-on-tab-why-calling-handleneeded-fixes-it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call `WebBrowser1.HandleNeeded;` before you call `WebBrowser1.Navigate`

Comment: Found this after having the exact same problem.  Worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you document. I have followed your instructions one page control, two tabs, webbrowser on second (invisible) tab.

To know if the page is loading, I have capture some events of the webbrowser. I see that `onBeforeNavigate`, `onTitleChange` and `OnNavigateComplete` all get fired without having to make second tabsheet visible.

Setting your javascript code to execute under one of those events may solve your problem.